# Configuring solr for omeka s solr module

Tags: solr, omeka

I'm trying to configure a solr container to work with the Solr module for Omeka S. Both containers run, but when I configure the module to connect to localhost:8983/solr/omeka-s is says Solr HTTP Error 7: 'Couldn't connect to server'. I'm new to both omeka and solr and could really use some help.

Dockerfile

```
FROM solr:9.2
LABEL maintainer="ccordero@csusb.edu"

ENV OMEKA_S_CONFIGSET_PATH=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/omeka-s/conf

USER root

RUN mkdir -p $OMEKA_S_CONFIGSET_PATH
COPY * $OMEKA_S_CONFIGSET_PATH/
RUN chown -R solr:solr $OMEKA_S_CONFIGSET_PATH

USER solr
```

schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="omeka-s" version="1.6">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" />
  </types>

  <fields>
    <!-- The unique ID field for the documents. You can change the name if required. -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- Custom fields -->
    <field name="resource_name_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="sites_id_is" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="is_public_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- Additional fields can be added here if needed. -->

  </fields>

  <!-- Unique key field -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>9.4</luceneMatchVersion>

  <!-- Custom request handlers (optional) -->
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- Use the default search component -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Request handler for updating documents -->
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />

  <!-- Custom field types -->
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" />

  <fields>
    <!-- The unique ID field for the documents. You can change the name if required. -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- Custom fields -->
    <field name="resource_name_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="sites_id_is" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="is_public_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- Additional fields can be added here if needed. -->

  </fields>

  <!-- Unique key field -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

</config>
```